# ASP.NET MVC - Bootstrap 5 modal button does not display dropdownlist items

Tags: model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

After beating my head against this problem for 3 days, I think I finally narrowed it down to an issue with the bootstrap modal button. I have modal button popup that displays a partial view, and a select list within that. When I create it to a separate page, it displays with no issues:

dropdownlistworking

[image: 1]

However, when I put the exact same code into my modal button view, the dropdown stops displaying my items except for the default:

dropdownlistnotworking

[image: 2]

Here is the code on the modal button:

Main view:

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addDoc">Add Doc</button>
  <div id="addDoc" class="modal fade"">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        @Html.Partial("_AddDoc", new Slingshot.Models.OrgDocsModel { OrgId = @Model.First().OrgId}) 
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Partial:

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="addDocLabel">Add Document</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"  aria-label="Close"> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                             
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="_AddDoc">
   
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgId" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DocName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DocName" class="form-control" />
             </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label asp-for="DocTypeName" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="DocTypeName" asp-items="@Model.DocTypesList"  class="form-control" >
                 
            </select>
                         
        </div>
     
         <div class="form-group">
             <input asp-for="UploadFile" class="custom-file-input" id = "OrgDoc">Choose File</input>
             <label class="custom-file-label" for="OrgDoc" class="form-control"</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You are not passing in you `DocTypesList`, as far as I can see. The only thing you are giving to your partial view is an `OrgId`

Comment: @marco how do I do that? Sorry, I am brand new at this figuring it out as I go- really appreciate any help!!